# convert utc time to localtime in different browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, momentjs

Converting UTC time into local system time is not working in Firefox, but it's working in Chrome.

```js
var utctime = '2019-12-09 05:33:48';
var localtime = moment.utc(utctime , 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss').local().format("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm");

console.log(localtime);
```

If I change the timezone and I'm getting correct output from Chrome, but in Firefox the date is not updating.
chrome:-  2019-12-09 11:03 pm
firefox:- 2019-12-09 10:33 pm

Comment: how do you change the timezone ?

Comment: I put this in codesandbox and it renders just fine in both FF and Chrome: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-resonance-c7y79

Comment: i dont think its your code - https://support.mozilla.org/bm/questions/1247616

Comment: change system timezone and run in both browsers and check the difference. I observed as i said its working in chrome but its not working in firefox